# install gigablast. make file not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, installation, gnu-make

I am trying to install gigablast on a server. I have not been able to get past the make file part. I have used it to create other programs but I also don't have a degree in server or computer programming, and thats why I need help.

I am running ubunto 14.04 and have updated everything. I unzipped the file in the root folder. Was I supposed to move it the the var folder? I have not found a install file or a make file for initill construction and have done make -f and make -i 
I get that it is a directory but can't find the file to point it to. 
This is the list of files on github
https://github.com/gigablast/open-source-search-engine

THis has the install guide.
https://www.gigablast.com/faq.html#src

Thank you for helping me out

Comment: There is a file named Makefile in the repository you linked to.  You'll need to copy these files to any empty directory and then run make.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ mkdir gigablast
$ cd gigablast
$ wget --no-check-certificate "https://github.com/gigablast/open-source-search-engine/archive/master.zip"
$ unzip master.zip
$ cd open-source-search-engine-master/
$ make
```